# HTTP 304 Not Modified Response Taking Several Seconds

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, windows-server-2008, http-status-code-304

I am building an ASP.NET application. I'm experiencing some slow load times so I checked out the traffic using Fiddler. It seems that the page itself is loading in around 3 seconds.

OK, it's kind of slow, but what baffles me is how long the js, css, and image assets take to load, even when they're being cached. It is taking the HTTP request 3 seconds before it responds with a 304. Now, I've done my share of web development, and my understanding is that a 304 response should not take 3 seconds.

My suspicion is that the server that the app is hosted is too weak. It is a VM running Windows Server 2K8 SP2 with about 2GB of memory, and the physical machine has at least one other VM running concurrently. Before I go and get myself a new server, does the lack of power in the machine sound like a possible cause of this problem?

Note: Latency should not be a problem; I'm accessing it through an intranet.

Comment: It depends on. I was playing StarCraft2 on WinXP machine, which hosted a site 10k unique users/day with 2GB RAM. With no detectable drop in perfomance. I used Apache+nginx, though.

Comment: Yes, the efficiency of the server serving the static content matters.... A LOT. Also *how* that server is caching the static content and serving it matters. Note that none of this has to do with bandwidth, because, as you stated both servers are on the intranet.